# Can't multiline UILabel on iOS 8.3 using xCode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

With autolayout on `xCode 7.2` I can't multiline UILabel on `iOS 8.3` while it is getting very well multiline on `iOS 9.2`. I am sure it is due to version I currently am. Earlier with the same constraints I was able to multiline using `xCode 6.3` for `iOS 8.3`.

Constraints are :

[image]

and `numberoflines set to 0`

Comment: What about height of your parentView contain label, does parentView large than 52pt ?

Comment: @sticker yes yes it is a lot larger around 200pt.

Comment: on your ios simulator select Debug -> Color blended layers to see does label is show correct frame

Comment: I recommend checking the lineBreakMode property

Comment: The best way is take a snapshot of your interfacebuider with views and constraints so we can easy to know the problem.

Comment: y do u have content hugging to 251 for both horizontal and vertical ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you

first set
   line breaks Mode=Word Warp 
and then give number of lines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do is reset the layout engine for this particular label. After setting label's text. Now it works fine in iOS 7,8 and 9. Still don't why this solved version issues.

```
[lblName layoutIfNeeded];
```